# webapp instances approach

Tags: django, web-applications, database-design, architecture

I'm wondering about how can I modeling a webapp in order to provide  services to several clients at same time, running like a instance for every one.
In example if I'm providing a basic erp software for a client, and I want give this service
to everyone that want use it online with their own data...

How can I do that?

I'm thinking in a main webapp like a gateway to login the users and route them to their
own webapp, but, is really needed a approach like this? with my approach do I need a db for every
client?, and maybe  it will be a big mess...

What another approach can I apply for this case?

Any comment are welcome..

Comment: why not a database that supports multiple clients?  i.e. update your schema to support many clients

Comment: Is there a specific requirement for a single database per client?  Is the functionality of each client's web app the same?

Comment: Every client will have the same functionality, but every one can have their own data set...

Comment: @SB.Im talking about users, sorry... I'm only asking, maybe I'm really confused about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each model can easily have a `user` field which is a ForeignKey to your User model. Each model instance could then be associated with a user and each user would log into a single webapp with a single database. Of course your views must then handle filtering and authenticating access to each model instance:

```
class Resource(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    someattr = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


def show_resources(request):
    resources = Resource.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    render_to_response("view.html", {'resources': resources})
```